# How can I build a model that could predict that a credit card transaction is fraud or not based on previous transactions of the same card

Tags: machine-learning, fraud-detection

I am working on a project where I am supposed to detect fraud in credit card transaction. I generated a dataset that looks like this:
[image: dataset]

supposedly this is the transactions in a database. The job consists in taking the decision to perform an OTP verification or accept the transaction directly. My thought is to put a condition on the credit card number if it's present in the database then I could compare it to previous transactions automatically through a machine learning model. if the informations in the transaction ( ip address, billing address...) are identical to the previous transactions of the same card in the trained model then it's normal. Else, depending on the different fields it could be classified as an anomaly.
I tried to use the Isolation Forest algorithm as it looks more convenient for this task, but I don't get the results I want. Any suggestions are welcome.

Ps: note that the dataset contains fully repeated rows, as well as repeated rows with the same card and different other fields ( supposedly fraud).

Comment: My bank has VG, aggressive CC fraud alert system. Twice waiters have kept a copy of my credit card info and tried using it. Typical first step is to try to use the card for a deposit on a hotel/motel reservation. Every time the bank system alerts me about use of my card outside of my usual orbit. Also it I bungle the PIN number on a purchase (easy to do with plastic anti-COVID keypad cover) and then try again, system alerts me next day of the failed attempt. If I use the card to make unusual online purchase, alert follows. My too-predictable life helps. Routine use goes smoothly w/out alerts.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for your comment, that's exactly the goal here. It's to make the life easier for cardholders by not doing the extra verification unless there is a probability of fraud.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please have a look at the [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour). Questions asking for general advice are unfortunately off topic here. You can edit your question to describe a more specific problem.